# mifare classic 4k reading to human readable form

Tags: nfc, smartcard, rfid, mifare

i have mifare classic 4k and ACR1281U reader. I can authenticate/read/load succesfully.I have search the sites how to read the NFC tags but I am missing some; here are my questions

1. how to read and convert the data from MIfare blocks to human readable form
2. how to change the default auth key.

## EDIT

Ok I just found out something strange. I tried to authenticate the random sector trailor  block with the 
key A

```
FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

then i tried to read that trailor block i found this

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF 90 00
```

what i am confused is acccording to documentation, in the sector trailer
the key A comes first then access bits and then key b then response status

now what i get is

```
keyb? | access bits | key A | response status
```

Note : i tried to authenticated with Key A which is FFFFFFFFFFFF and successfully authenticated.

could anyone explain this to me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So which format is your data in?

Comment: MiFare 4K can contain any data that can be encoded within 4KiB. Also, human readable is kind of a relative notion.

Comment: mifare data is all in Hex format.

Comment: JUST UPDATED and my purpose is to overwrite the key A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a sector you need to authenticate on that sector with keyB. Then you can overwrite the key block as:

```
new Key A | access bits | Key B
```

Comment: OK. i did what you said. and it was successful. I can not authenticate with default key FFFFFFFFFFFF anymore. yay!!!!. I tried to authenticat with the new key A and it was successful, yay!!!. but I read the sector trailor again, but i still see the 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF 90 00. where is my new key?

Comment: your key is in the last block of the sector. read here: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S703x.pdf . i suppose the tag don't send you data that you have already.

Comment: thanks for clarification, yes i understand the auth data is stored in the last block(trailor block) in a sector. I write the block 3 which is the last block of sector 0 but when i read the block 3 again it shows 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF 90 00. I also found out that when i update the same data in block 2 it shows the updated value but not block 3 though.kinda interesting though. may be something is masking/blocking the authentication bits so it will not be displayed by the readers i guess. Thanks